# caption package breaks centering of a floating listing's caption

Tags: horizontal-alignment, listings

I tend to use (floating) listings, as you can observe below in the MWE.
To set the width of those listings, `xleftmargin` and `xrightmargin` are set to equal values to mimic centering of the listing.

I saw unexpected behaviour using the caption package, in the following condition:
Depending on the resulting width of the listing, the listing's caption does not respect the justification and is not centered.
Simply removing `\usepackage{caption}` (and `\captionsetup` therefore too of course) puts the caption right in the center where it is intended to appear.

So i suspect the caption package is overwriting sth. Can this be corrected in a simple way without hacking with minipage/figure/tabular-environments?

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption} %removing it centeres the listing's caption again

\captionsetup{
    %... some modification
    justification = centering, % does not help with the listing's caption
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[
    frame=shadowbox %helper, to see listing's dim
    ,captionpos=b
    ,float
    %center the listing
        ,xleftmargin=.20\textwidth
        ,xrightmargin=.20\textwidth
    ,label=code
    ,caption={This caption is not centered at all}
    ,language=Delphi]
i := 1;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428101/package-listings-set-caption-position-posotion-top-works-fine-but-option-bott

Comment: Meanwhile, the issue has been fixed upstream: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/commit/0a32b2b8d4f814c58da1969ac7f38c7f9ec8f183. This is included in current texlive.