# Package listings, set caption position, option top works fine, but bottom does not

Tags: listings

I would like that caption position is at the center of the page, like the one at the top in my example.

Here my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\lstdefinestyle{SC}{
    language=erlang,
    xleftmargin=.2\textwidth,
    xrightmargin=.2\textwidth
}

\lstset{ 
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    basicstyle=\scriptsize,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showspaces=false,
    commentstyle=\color{blue},
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{purple},
    captionpos=t,
    frame=lines
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=SC, caption={test}]
% Stop all containers
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
% Delete all containers
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
% Delete all images
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The image shows the problem.

[image]

How can I set the caption to be centered? I have not found a solution in the package documentation.

Comment: If you drop the `caption` package, then the listings caption is centered, both with the `t` and the `b` positions.  Do you have to load the caption package for something else?

Comment: Deleting `caption` package has no effect in my code :-(, result is the same. thx

Comment: What is the version of your `listings` package?  (Add `\listfiles` to your file before `\documentclass` and look in the log for the information.)  It works for me with `listings` version `2015/06/04 1.6`

Comment: My version is `1.6` from `2015-11-10 22:01:23` installed via miktex package manager.

Comment: My log is to big for this comment, here link to pastebin [LOG](https://pastebin.com/YBDi2cwh). In my log are three files for listings described, but why?

Comment: Hmm...I can't see any significant difference in those file listings.  Are you sure you are running the posted code?

Comment: ok, here [LOG ON PASTEBIN](https://pastebin.com/Wnc1Jaw1) is complete log, thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug has been fixed in the caption package (https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/commit/0a32b2b8d4f814c58da1969ac7f38c7f9ec8f183) and is included in current texlive for about half a year now.

Answer (score 4):

It is imho a bug in `caption`. With your `xleftmargin` setting you are reducing the linewidth but caption doesn't take this into account for captions below the listing.

There is actually already a bug report: https://github.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/1.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{listings}


\usepackage[justification=centering,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\makeatletter

 \def\lst@MakeCaption#1{% #1 is `t' or `b'
    \begingroup 
      \caption@setposition{#1}%
      \caption@iftop{%
        \ifdim\hsize>\linewidth
          \hsize\linewidth
        \fi
        \@tempdima\belowcaptionskip
        \belowcaptionskip\abovecaptionskip
        \abovecaptionskip\@tempdima}
        {\ifdim\hsize>\dimexpr \linewidth + \lst@xleftmargin + \lst@xrightmargin\relax
          \hsize\dimexpr \linewidth + \lst@xleftmargin + \lst@xrightmargin\relax
        \fi}%
      \caption@setup{rule=0}%
      \caption@setoptions{lstlisting}%
      \caption@setautoposition{#1}%
      \caption@begin{lstlisting}%
        \caption@ORI@lst@MakeCaption{#1}%
      \caption@end
    \endgroup}%
\makeatother

\lstdefinestyle{SC}{
    language=erlang,
    xleftmargin=.2\textwidth,
    xrightmargin=.2\textwidth
}

\lstset{
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    basicstyle=\scriptsize,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showspaces=false,
    commentstyle=\color{blue},
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{purple},
    captionpos=t,
    frame=lines
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=SC, caption={test},captionpos=t]
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=SC, caption={test},captionpos=b]
% Stop all containers
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
% Delete all containers
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
% Delete all images
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, this work in my example, thx. But in my realy work, I see error `pdflatex.exe> ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
pdflatex.exe> \caption@@ifinlist #1#2->\begingroup 
pdflatex.exe>                                      \def \@tempa ##1,#1,##2\@nil {\endgroup...
pdflatex.exe> l.9 Tendermint}, captionpos=b]{code/tender_att.sh}` and pdf file is not produced. :-(

Comment: You need to provide a minimal example.

Comment: I have written in github discussion: [On github](https://github.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/1), thx.

Comment: It is *very* impolite to sent such a large code (which quite probably won't even show the error as all the includes are missing).

Answer (score 2):

As per comments, removing the caption package and changing to `captionpos=b` gives a centered caption

[image: Sample output]

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{SC}{
    language=erlang,
    xleftmargin=.2\textwidth,
    xrightmargin=.2\textwidth
}

\lstset{
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    basicstyle=\scriptsize,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showspaces=false,
    commentstyle=\color{blue},
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{purple},
    captionpos=b,
    frame=lines
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=SC, caption={test}]
% Stop all containers
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
% Delete all containers
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
% Delete all images
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

This is with the following versions of the files

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   color.sty    2016/07/10 v1.1e Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
listings.sty    2015/06/04 1.6 (Carsten Heinz)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
 lstmisc.sty    2015/06/04 1.6 (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg    2015/06/04 1.6 listings configuration
supp-pdf.mkii
lstlang1.sty    2015/06/04 1.6 listings language file
lstlang2.sty    2015/06/04 1.6 listings language file
lstlang3.sty    2015/06/04 1.6 listings language file
 ***********
```